# How to pass id from (form) of view blade to route (web.php) :Route

Tags: laravel, routes

I need to pass an id to the route (web.php) from the form. My application has comment section at opporunities/id **(id in value)** , Whenever non-Auth user submits comment , my app will ask login and redirects to  /opportunities but i need /opportunities/id.  
 In the form of comment i have submitted page id. I have setup my route as 
**Route::post('/opportunities', 'OpportunitiesController@postPost')->name('posts.post');** 
 Now if i can pass that id to as /opportunities/id then after login user will automatically lands on that page.  I have manually tested and attached id and it works. 
 Do I need to use **"use Illuminate\Http\Request;"** to get form data to web.php (route)? to get request post id?  All i need is to add id after Route:post('/opportunites/').  Any suggestion and help will be appropriated.

Comment: add 
Route::post('/opportunities/{Id}', 'OpportunitiesController@postPost')->name(' opportunities');. And in comment blade pass url like this {{route('opportunities',$returnvalue->I'd)}}

Comment: It didn't work but i passed returnvalue as parameter like this action="{{route('opportunities',['returnvalue'=> $post['id']]) }}"  and worked flawlessly. I need to thank you still for showing the way. @bipin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was and figured out is that

action="{{route('opportunities',['returnvalue'=> $post['id']]) }}" I still got error @bipin answer but i passed it with as parameter and solved. Thanks bipin for suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be, pass your post id inside the form

**View Blade**

```
{{ Form::hidden('post_id', 'value', array('id' => 'post_id')) }}
```

**Controler**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    public function comment(Request $request)
    {
      //Validation            
      $this->validate($request, [
           'post_id' => 'required'
      ]);
      //Inside variable
      $input = $request->all();
      // OR
       $request->post_id;          
    }
```

Comment: If it was controller i would happy to use it.  It was to work with routes (web.php). Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: in your solution wath happen if user change manualy post_id in browser ??